# LINQ, Filtering out attachments with mappings

Tags: c#, linq, list, filter, lambda

I have a list of mappings
with a property and a value

and i have a list of attachments
typical File info.

what i wanna do is to search trough the attachment and make sure that the filename contains
txt or xls format.

```
public class Mapping
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Property { get; set; }
public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class file
{
public byte[] data {get;set;}
public string filename{get;set;}
}
```

and i will have the result in LISTs

```
var mappings = new List<Mapping>(){
new Mapping{Property="Filter", Value="txt"},
new Mapping{Property="Filter", Value="xls"}

};

   var files = new List<file>();




var filterdFiles = files.Where(x=> mappings.All(m=>x.filename.contains(m.Value)))
```

but i dont get any result so i think the Linq is wrong, anybody with master experise?

Comment: Try `mappings.Any` instead of `mappings.All`

Comment: `.All` means that every file must contain _all_ extensions. Try Any instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var filterdFiles = files
                   .Where(x=> 
                          mappings.Any(m=>x.filename.contains(m.Value)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
var filterdFiles = files.Where(x => mappings.Where(m => m.Property == "Filter")
                                            .Any(m => x.filename.Contains(m.Value)));
```